# Javascript Object population

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have a database of records, here called `recordDOM`, and that I need to split its length to fit a specific size limit.

The following snippet of code doesn't work. It yields a TypeError: `TypeError: packet[packetCount] is undefined`

```
var packet = {};
var packetCount = 0;
var elementCount = 0;

$.each(recordDOM, function(index, element) {
    if (elementCount >= 168) {
        packetCount++;
        elementCount = 0
    }

    if (typeof element != "undefined") {
        packet[packetCount][elementCount] = element;
    }
    elementCount++;
});
```

I've tried initializing the `packet`variable as an Array, and several other minor edits to the code above, but I'm obviously missing something. Can you please enlighten me?

[**EDIT**] Desired output would be:

```
packet = {
    "0": {
        "0": {
            // First Element
        },
        "1": {
            // Second Element
        },
        ...
        "167": {
            // Last element of the first packet
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "0": {
            // First Element of the second packet
        },
        "1": {
            // Second Element
        },
        ...
        "167": {
            // Last element of the second packet
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please change if (typeof  element  != undefined)

Comment: You are trying to access a property of `packet[1]` but you haven't assigned anything to it.

Comment: @Avihaym You mean `if (typeof element != "undefined")`.

Comment: Adding `if (!packet[packetCount]){packet[packetCount] = {};}` before `packet[packetCount][elementCount] = element;` should fix it.

Comment: @Xufox Yes..but i cant edit my comment :\

Comment: @Fran Initializating `packet[packetCount] = {}` gets rid of the error. I have all my packets in the resulting object, but with only the last element of the records. For example: `packet[0][0]` is undefined but `packet[0][167]` has an element. Same goes for the other packets.

Comment: @Fluffy `packet[0][0]` could be undefined if `element` is undefined the first time around. Maybe you should do `elementCount++;` only if there was an element? Using the debugger console you can add `console.log(element)` or similar where needed to see what's going on or add `debugger;` and step through your code to fix any logical errors.

Comment: @Fran Yes, I'd already done that, I'll update my code, but the issue remains :/ I'm logging all the elements that should be copied to the packet array, and none of those are undefined.

Comment: @Fluffy - Place a breakpoint at `packet[packetCount][elementCount] = element;` and see what the values are of the first time the code adds anything. If `packetCount` and `elementCount` are both `0` and `element` has a desired value but later on `packet[0][0]` is undefined then I can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to initialize the inner Object,

```
var packet = {};
var packetCount = 0;
var elementCount = 0;

$.each(recordDOM, function(index, element) {
    if (elementCount >= 168) {
        packetCount++;
        elementCount = 0
    }

    if (element != undefined) {
        if(!packet[packetCount]){
          packet[packetCount] = {};      // Change is here
        }
        packet[packetCount][shipCount] = element;
    }
    shipCount ++;
});
```

Comment: This is incorrect as `packet.packetCount` is not the same as `packet[packetCount]` Your if statement initializes `packet.packetCount` and will leave `packet[packetCount] still undefined`

Comment: Thanks for your input. Initializating `packet[packetCount] = {}` gets rid of the error. I have all my packets in the resulting object, but with only the last element of the records. For example: packet[0][0] is undefined but packet[0][167] has an element. Same goes for the other packets. Do you have an idea?

Comment: `packet` is not an array. It's an object. `0`, `167` are properties of that object, not indexes We are initializing only the property `167`, not `0`.

Comment: If you want to make it an array, just initialize `packet` as `var packet = []`

Comment: Either way, I only get the last index/property (here being 167) initialized.

Comment: Yes. That is how it works. What you want to do? Do you want to initialize all indexes in between with zero or empty object or any?

Comment: I want to cycle through all the elements of the record (hence the each function) and copy each element in the packet array (or object, it doesn't really matter but I suppose array is more efficient?), and this divided by 167. So each cell of `packet`, from 0 to 167, should be defined

Comment: Okay. You have an element for index `167`. So `packet[167]` will be an object(Array). From index `0` through `166`, the value will be `undefined`(by default). What do you want to make it? Empty array?

Comment: Okay perhapsI misunderstood something, I apologize. The `each` function cycles through all the elements in the recordDOM object, right?. So, for each of those, the `element` var is a defined object that I want to copy to a 2 dimensionals array: `packet[packetCount][myElement]`. The end result should get me: `packet[0][0] = firstElement`, `packet[0][1] = secondElement` etc until I reach the packet size (167), then move on to `packet[1][0]`, `packet [1][1]` etc ... and supposedly never `undefined`! I'm editing my question with a desired output

Comment: Ha, I get it now ... `packet[packetCount] = {};` re-initializes the object on each iteration. I'm so blind. Just check if `elementCount == 0` and we're good. Thank you for your help!